# Getting "_id : 000000000" for every get request

Tags: mongodb, api, go, get

I have recently started working with GO and tried to create an API. This was a basic API with few `get` and `post` endpoints. Every endpoint is working just fine but one. I am doing the same thing as in the other get endpoints but don't understand why am I getting the empty instance back from the mongoDB. And as far as I can guess, I think this is the problem due to data type.
 This is my `Post` struct.

```
package models

import (
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

type Posts struct {
    Id       primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id" validate:"nil=false"`
    Caption  string             `json:"caption" bson:"caption"`
    ImageUrl string             `json:"imageUrl" bson:"imageUrl" validate:"nil=false"`
    Author   string             `json:"author" bson:"author" validate:"nil:false"`
    Time     time.Time          `json:"time" bson:"time"`
}
```

This is the controller `getPost`

```
package controller

import (
    "insta/models"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    // "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

func GetPost(c *gin.Context) {
    var post models.Posts
    postId := c.Param("postId")
    client, ctx, cancel := getConnection()
    defer cancel()
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    err := client.Database("instagram").Collection("posts").FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": postId}).Decode(&post)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get the Post")
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"post": post})
}
```

This is my `main`

```
package main

import (
    "insta/controller"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/posts/:postId" , controller.GetPost)
    router.Run()
}
```

I am getting this response.

[image]

`PostId` is valid

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the postId from the param is of type `string` while the postId in mongodb is of type `primitive.ObjectID` which are not the same.

The solution is to convert it to a MongoDB `ObjectID` before querying.

```
func GetPost(c *gin.Context) {
    var post models.Posts
    postId := c.Param("postId")
    postObjectId, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(postId)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "PostID is not a valid ObjectID"})
        return
    }

    client, ctx, cancel := getConnection()
    defer cancel()
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    err = client.Database("instagram").Collection("posts").FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": postObjectId}).Decode(&post)
    // Check if document exists return 404 error
    if errors.Is(err, mongo.ErrNoDocuments) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Post with the given id does not exist"})
        return
    }

    // Mongodb network or server error
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"message": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"post": post})
}
```